# function email and name changing

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make function on Google spreadsheet (JavaScript). My understanding of java script is very low but would like to know basics. any help would be appreciated.

I have information that has capital of last name and Name. but I want to make that capital of last name in the end of name and add gmail in the end. for example IJOSH make it JoshIgmail by using function

=Letter("IJOSH") -> "JoshIgmail" so start by moving capital (last name ) to the end, result in JoshI. Finally, add "gmail" in the end

```
function("letter"){
    var letter;
    return(etter+L+gmail)
}
```

Comment: Were waiting in anticipation... who gets the correct answer points!

Answer (score 4):

You could get this rearrangement with a simple regular expression:

```js
var _value = "IJOSH",
    suffix = "gmail";

_value.replace( /^(.)(.*)$/, "$2$1" + suffix );
```

This results in "JOSH" being moved to the front, "I" being moved to the middle, and "gmail" being appended to the end of the string.

[image: Regular Expression Demonstration]

The pattern used is fairly straight-forward. The `/` and `/` indicate the beginning and end of the pattern. `^` and `$` denote the front and back of the string, meaning we don't want to match on subsets, but on the entire string itself.

When we wrap something in `(` and `)` we create a *capture class*, allowing us to later reference it like `$1` or `$2` (depending on which capture class it was). In regex, `.` represents *any character*. We modify this in the second capture class with `*`, which means the previous pattern (`.` in this case) can be found *0 or more times*.

Comment: Pooosshhh.  Mind Blown!

Comment: Thank you, demonstration is very nice. what is $2 $1 means?

Comment: @user3466687 Please see latest addition for full explanation.

Comment: Thank you, Its now clear about code languages that you used. would it be possible to do other peoples names? for example, on spreadsheet use =gmail(Name) and return ameNgmail? ( in this case var should be "")?

Comment: @user3466687 The above approach will work regardless whose name you place in the `_value` variable.

Comment: so I have to type persons name every time i change? I type this on google java script     function gMail() var _value = "IJOSH",
    suffix = "gmail";

_value.replace( /^(.)(.*)$/, "$2$1" + suffix );

Comment: I got it. Thank you, it worked. again, thanks for clear "moving" demonstration.

Comment: @user3466687 If you have accepted this approach as the best solution for you, it is encouraged that you click the checkmark beside it to inform other users that this worked best for you.

Answer (score 1):

do you mean something line:

```
function someTest() {
    var str = "lJOSH";
    var result = str.substr(1).toLowerCase() + str.substr(0, 1) + "gmail";
    return result.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + result.slice(1);
}
console.log( someTest("lJOSH") ); //returns Joshlgmail
```

Comment: Thank you for helping with me. I will try that too.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways, but heres that I would do:

```
//example call would be createEmail("IJOSH")
function createEmail(inputName) {
    //String Assigned to a name variable
    var name = inputName;

    //Split it into individual letters as an array
    var letters = name.split(""); //["I", "J", "O", "S", "H"];

    //Treat it as a queue and remove first letter (assign it to a variable)
    var fLetter = letters.shift();

    //Push it to end of stack
    letters.push(fLetter);

    //Put them back together and the 'gmail' string to the end
    var email = letters.join("") + "gmail"; //JOSHIgmail

    return email;
}
```

This is a long typed way to do this, but a good way to learn about strings and arrays.

EDIT: Not the sexiest solution but hopefully easy to understand

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation. So there would be three var below function name. ( I need to define function on the top right?) yes i would like to know about strings and arrays. this may be a stupid question, but I would like to confirm that string is referring to as words correct?

Comment: yeah, I would wrap all of that in a function like so function (inputName) { var name = inputName.... } and just return email at the end of the function.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this on spreadsheet and worked fine. one more thing why its email in the end? is it necessary to code this?

Comment: when you return the string at the end, you can assign it to a variable like:  var userEmail = createEmail('IJOSH'); so userEmail would now have the 'JOSHIgmail' assigned to it.

Comment: I got it now. Thank you very much jOshT.